# Android tool "Export signed application package" is inconsistent

Tags: android, eclipse, export, package

Android tool "Export signed application package" frequently generates faulty packages.  I am wondering if there is a way to fix it.

Here are some details:
An app's package is about 1.8 MB currently.  "Export signed application package" frequently generates a package with a smaller size (e.g. 800 KB, 1.7 MB, etc.).  These packages will crash immediately upon the start of the app.  I have learned this in a really hard way - complaints from the app users when a faulty package is published. Eclipse does not show any error messages when these faulty packages are generated. The only way that I check this is looking at the file size. Of course, the app is ensured to work without any problem before the export.  I believe the crashing error is "ClassNotFound" indicating that some components are not exported. This happens even after a fresh cleaning of the project. If I keep exporting, a correct package will be generated eventually. I usually need to do it no more than twice.

Any tip to remedy this will be greatly appreciated.